# Разобрать код построчно

Tags: c#

Вот код:

```
using System;

namespace Lab82
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the sentence: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] arr = str.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (arr.Length > 1)
            {
                str = "";
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
                    str += arr[i] + " ";
                str = arr[arr.Length - 1] + " " + str + arr[0];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Results: " + str);




            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не орать нужно, а озаглавить вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что код выполняет

Comment: @vikttur именно это автор и не понимает

Comment: автор, в чем вопрос? этот фрагмент кода если даже дословно на русский перевести будет уже понятно что это код делает.

Comment: Мне нужно не то, что исполняет, а что означает каждая строка

Comment: Какая именно строка вам непонятна?

Comment: string[] arr = str.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); и str = "";

Comment: эта строка режет исходную строку `str` по пробелам, получившийся массив нарезанных кусков сохраняет в переменную `arr`

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: На будущее - не надо кидать в вопросы всю простыню, выделяй непонятную строчку и задавай по ней конкретный вопрос с осмысленным названием, в таком виде вопрос - треш и практически не несёт пользы сообществу.

Comment: @teran, мое замечание о том, что в заголовке желательно отмечать и предназначение кода. Это нужно для будущих посетителей - по названию можно найти решение задачи. А разбирать построчно можно тысячи кодов... "*Перемещение слова в предложении. Разобрать код построчно*" - вариант?

Answer (score 3):

Вам даже гугл переводчик в целом способен объяснить что тут происходит, но целом будет как-то так

```
используем системыеФункции;

назовем это Lab82
{
    программа
    {
        основная функция программы(и ее аргументы)
        {
            Консоль.Пиши!("Введите предложение: ");
            строка str = Консоль.ЧитайСтроку();
            массив строк arr = строку str.Разделить(по пробелу, ОпцииРазделения.УдалитьПустые);
            Если (Длина arr > 1)
            {
                str = пустая строка
                Начиная с i = 1 до предпоследнего элемента массива каждый шаг по  +1)
                    str += arr[i] + " "; //соединим слова предложения обратно

               // а затем
                str = arr[последний элемент] + " " + str + arr[первый элемент];
            }
            Консоль.Пиши("Результат: " + str);


            ПодождемПокаПользовательЧто-тоНажмет();
        }
    }
}
```

то есть в целом, берется предложение, и его первое слово в перемещается в конец.

Comment: о, программист 1C детектед :) (шутка!)

Comment: @tym32167 1C в глаза не видел :) и не видеть бы :)

Comment: @teran ну примерно так и выглядит!

Comment: Вот не лень же было))

Comment: Почему в первом случае после `Консоль.Пиши` есть восклицательный знак, а во втором нет?!